# How to get facebook style notifications in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I am doing a project where I am using JSF 1.2. In this i'm designed employee names and exam names  these two names i'm getting dynamically.

In front end displaying normal format, now i want display in format of notifications like Facebook style.

It is possible in jsf?. I want change only GUI part.

This is my sample code

```
<f:view>

<h:dataTable var="emp" value="#{EmpBean.empList}" >
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Added Emplyoees"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{emp.empNames}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Names"></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{emp.examNames}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
<h:column>
</h:dataTable>

</f:view>
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: you could do this with the help of jquery http://www.9lessons.info/2014/09/facebook-style-notification-popup-using.html

Comment: You might be able to style primefaces' growl to look like facebook notification popups (if that's what you want). Demo: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml

Comment: @mohsin azeem: i tried in jquery but i don't know get dynamic data and dynamic count,so i'm shifted JSF

Comment: @Pieter De Bie:in my jsf1.2 require any primefaces instalattion?

Comment: IDK, you'll have to google that.

Comment: A 'recent' version of PrimeFaces is not available for jsf 1.2

Comment: @sri primefaces is not supported with jsf 1.xx